# docker: Error response from daemon: Ports are not available: listen tcp 0.0.0.0:3306: bind: address already in use

Tags: mysql, sql, docker, terminal, containers

Am getting this error in the terminal when setting up a container.

Eventually the database does initialise:

```
mysql: [Warning] Using a password on the command line interface can be insecure.
ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)
Initialized Database
```

But I then have trouble accessing it from the root user which makes me think the container isn't working properly.

Comment: seems like sql related more then docker , what image you use ? what is docker ps -a say ?

Comment: are you running mysql/mariadb on the host, as well as in a container? How are you starting the container? Which container image are you using?

Comment: @alex docker ps -a tell me the container has been created but does not specify a port

Comment: @danblack i'm still pretty new to docker so not exactly sure what a container image is? i was running mysql so i'm going to shut that down and give it another go

Comment: @danblack, it worked after shutting down mysql, thanks for the advice

Answer (score 2):

This is pretty common error. As **@danblack** already enlightened in comments, mysql is already running on host port 3306. There are two ways to solve this error (for linux)

> 1. kill mysql demon on host and then run docker container again.

```
$ sudo service stop mysql
$ docker run --name=test-mysql mysql
```

> 2. run mysql container on different port

```
$ docker run --name=test-mysql -p 3305:3306 mysql
```

Answer (score 2):

This worked for me in freeing up port 3306 used up by MySQL service

```
sudo launchctl unload -F /Library/LaunchDaemons/com.oracle.oss.mysql.mysqld.plist
```

Try this and try to load back your mySQL service up again using

```
sudo launchctl load -F /Library/LaunchDaemons/com.oracle.oss.mysql.mysqld.plist
```